# I can't click on a button using its ID in Puppeteer

Tags: mocha.js, puppeteer, prettier

I want to click on the logout button, but when I use id="logoutButton" , it doesn't work

```
<td><div id="logoutButton" class="menuTopTab right"><span class="icon-d-power"></span></div></td><td><div id="logoutButton" class="menuTopTab right"><span class="icon-d-power"></span></div></td>
```

Here is my code:

```
const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('URL', {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle0'
    })

    await page.type('#email', 'EMAIL', { delay: 10 })
    await page.type('#password', 'PASSWORD', { delay: 10 })

    await page.click('#login_button')
    await page.waitForNavigation({
        waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
      })

    page.waitForSelector('#logoutButton')
        .then(() => console.log('got it'))

    await page.click('#logoutButton')
    //await page.click('#confirmYes')
    //await page.waitForSelector('#ssoMessageText')
})
```

})

Comment: could you share (1) your puppeteer code so we could see what approach you try, (2) elaborate on what you mean by "it doesn't work",  (3) and the DOM pasted as text would be more useful than the screenshot, you can copy it in your DevTools 'Elements' tab and copy outerHTML, please?

Comment: if you have the `got it` console msg (so you are sure your log out button is loaded into the DOM) then you could try `await page.$eval('#logoutButton'), el => el.click());` in some rare cases the builtin `page.click` doesn't work, see [this Github issue](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1805) as reference and alternate solutions.

Comment: Ideally, please show the live site or an accurate [mcve] of it, because there's not enough here to reproduce the problem. Sites can have complex and arbitrary behavior that can't always be captured in a screenshot or copy+paste of the HTML. For example, if the element is in a frame or shadow root, then it won't be accessible directly. You should also use the `await Promise.all([page.click(...), page.waitForNavigation(...)])` idiom for waiting for nav triggers to avoid a race condition.